# Counting thread priority - Java

Tags: java, thread-priority

Goal: wanted to count how many number of times High Priority and Low Priority threads were accessed. 
//When I compile the following code, the 'h'(int h standing for high) remains zero but the 'l'(low) increases.

```
    class Priority implements Runnable {
    int high = 0; 
    int low = 0;
    int count; Thread thrd;
    static boolean stop = false;
    static String currentName;
     Priority(String name) {
      thrd = new Thread(this, name);
      count = 0;
      currentName = name;
     }
     public void run() {
     System.out.println(thrd.getName() + " starting.");
     do {
      count++;

      if(currentName.compareTo(thrd.getName()) != 0) {
       currentName = thrd.getName();
       System.out.println("In " + currentName);
       System.out.println("Name in thrd is " + thrd.getName());
       System.out.println("name in currentName is " + currentName);
       if ("High Priority" == currentName) h++;
       if ("Low Priority" == currentName) l++;
       }
      } while(stop == false && count<10);

     stop = true;
     System.out.println("\n" + thrd.getName() + " terminating.");
     }
    } 

    class PriorityDemo {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
      Priority mt1 = new Priority("High Priority");
      Priority mt2 = new Priority("Low Priority");
      mt1.thrd.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY+2);
      mt2.thrd.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-2);

      mt1.thrd.start();
      mt2.thrd.start();

      try {
       mt1.thrd.join();
       mt2.thrd.join();
       } catch(InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println("Main thread interrupted.");
      }

      System.out.println("\n High priority thread counted to " + mt1.count);
      System.out.println("'n Low priority thread counted to " + mt2.count);
      System.out.println("In 'mt1' \nhigh is " + mt1.h + " and low is " + mt1.l);
      System.out.println("In 'mt2' \nhigh is " + mt2.h + " and low is " + mt2.l);
     }
    }
```

The last two lines of the executed code are as follows:
high in mt1 is ***0*** low is (for e.g.)985
high in mt2 is ***0*** low is 985!

I also tried
// if ("High Priority" == thrd.getName()) h++;
   if ("Low Priority" == thrd.getName()) l++;
But this too didn't work out.

Comment: use "High Priority".equals(thrd.getName())

Comment: Or better an enum or final String/ int to denote "High Priority" ...

Comment: this seems buggy too. if(currentName.compareTo(thrd.getName()) != 0) {
       currentName = thrd.getName(); Other thing is thread programs are fun but useless for most app developers. focus on j2ee and collections ... unless your in school and this is academic

Comment: use 'equals()' method instead of '==' operator in your condition.

Comment: what were you expecting and why?

Comment: @ tgkprog
Thank you 
That worked! :D

Comment: I wanted to count how many number of times High Priority and Low Priority threads were accessed.

Answer (score 0):

This might help. if I assumed your goals correctly

```
    package tst;

public class PriorityDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Priority mtHigh = new Priority(Priority.HIGH);
        Priority mtLow = new Priority(Priority.LOW);
        mtHigh.thrd.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY + 3);
        mtLow.thrd.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 3);

        mtHigh.thrd.start();
        mtLow.thrd.start();

        try {
            mtHigh.thrd.join();
            mtLow.thrd.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Main thread interrupted.");
        }

        System.out.println("v 2\n High priority thread counted to " + mtHigh.count);
        System.out.println("'n Low priority thread counted to " + mtLow.count);
        System.out.println("In 'mtHigh' \nhigh is " + mtHigh.high + " and low is " + mtHigh.low);
        System.out.println("In 'mtLow' \nhigh is " + mtLow.high + " and low is " + mtLow.low);
    }
}

class Priority implements Runnable {
    public final static String HIGH = "High Priority";
    public final static String LOW = "Low Priority";
    int high = 0;
    int low = 0;
    int count;
    Thread thrd;
    static boolean stop = false;
    String currentName;// why static?

    Priority(String name) {
        thrd = new Thread(this, name);
        count = 0;
        currentName = name;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(thrd.getName() + " starting.");
        do {
            count++;
            System.out.println("\nThrd " + thrd.getName() + " count " + count);
            if (thrd.getName().contains(currentName)) {
                // currentName = thrd.getName();
                //System.out.println("In " + currentName);
                System.out.println("Name in thrd is " + thrd.getName());
                System.out.println("name in currentName is " + currentName);
                if (currentName.contains(HIGH))
                    high++;
                if (currentName.contains(LOW))
                    low++;
            }
        } while (stop == false && count < 10);

        stop = true;//this static so high runs faster and stops low before its count is 10
        System.out.println("\n" + thrd.getName() + " terminating.");
    }
}
```

Output I got :

> Low Priority starting. High Priority starting.
>
> Thrd Low Priority count 1
>
> Thrd High Priority count 1 Name in thrd is High Priority Name in thrd
>   is Low Priority name in currentName is Low Priority name in
>   currentName is High Priority
>
> Thrd High Priority count 2 Name in thrd is High Priority name in
>   currentName is High Priority
>
> Thrd High Priority count 3 Name in thrd is High Priority name in
>   currentName is High Priority
>
> Thrd Low Priority count 2 Name in thrd is Low Priority name in
>   currentName is Low Priority
>
> Thrd High Priority count 4
>
> Thrd Low Priority count 3 Name in thrd is Low Priority name in
>   currentName is Low Priority Name in thrd is High Priority name in
>   currentName is High Priority
>
> Thrd Low Priority count 4 Name in thrd is Low Priority
>
> Thrd High Priority count 5 Name in thrd is High Priority name in
>   currentName is High Priority
>
> Thrd High Priority count 6 Name in thrd is High Priority name in
>   currentName is Low Priority
>
> Thrd Low Priority count 5 Name in thrd is Low Priority name in
>   currentName is Low Priority
>
> Thrd Low Priority count 6 Name in thrd is Low Priority name in
>   currentName is Low Priority
>
> Thrd Low Priority count 7 Name in thrd is Low Priority name in
>   currentName is Low Priority
>
> Thrd Low Priority count 8 Name in thrd is Low Priority name in
>   currentName is Low Priority
>
> Thrd Low Priority count 9 Name in thrd is Low Priority name in
>   currentName is Low Priority
>
> Thrd Low Priority count 10 Name in thrd is Low Priority name in
>   currentName is Low Priority
>
> Low Priority terminating. name in currentName is High Priority
>
> High Priority terminating. v 2  High priority thread counted to 6 'n
>   Low priority thread counted to 10 In 'mtHigh'  high is 6 and low is 0
>   In 'mtLow'  high is 0 and low is 10

Comment: he can go with synchronization also. either he can create Synchronize  block or method.

Comment: There is no need to Synchronize.no two mutable variables are accessed across threads. Well except for stop, but its hardly an issue as it just becomes true in one place and checked in other thread. doubt there will be any side effect in a academic project, except that the low priority thread will run for an extra iteration.

Comment: Thank you tgkprog once again! And also to you Prashant, for your suggestion :D

Comment: Mark it as the answer as you say it worked. See [faq] on why to do that.

Comment: AtomicBoolean can be used / stop.get()/ stop.set(true) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html more info. In this case better than sync i think. @Prashant